# Check whether an array contains some data

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, lodash

I have 2 variables,  `users` and `friend` inside a component

Variable `users` is an array. Each iteration contains `id`, `name` and `email`

Variable `friend` have same structure in addition to `pivot`.

In my components file (.vue file), I need to check whether `users` contains `friend` without using loops so that I can use it inside the `v-if` condition.

**Note**: `email` and `id` are unique values.

How can I check it? Single line code will be very helpful.

Eg:

`users` have 2 iterations

- id: 1
- name: First
- email: first@example.com
- id: 2
- name: Second
- email: second@example.com

`friend` is like this

- id: 2
- name: Second
- email: second@example.com
- pivot: {...}

Comment: can you provide examples of the two variables?

Comment: you can use sizeof() to check weather there it's empty or not

Comment: @GauravGupta I want to check wheather the array contains the datas of friend variable conditionally not to check wheather the array is empty or not

Comment: @Conor try this https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp

Comment: You can use the array `find()` function, something like `users.find(user => user.id === friend.id)`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, code will be helpful.

Comment: Try to use lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex 
`v-if="_.findIndex(friend, { 'id': 'userId' })"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.find()` lodash function

```
_.find(users, {id: friend.id});
```

The first parameter is the array which you want to check and the second is the condition to satisfy. Remember this will return the specific iteration of the array instead of true or false but you can use it as a condition. If it returns null then it will take it as false, if there is something then it will be taken as true.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `v-if`:

```
<div v-if=":user.friend"></div>
```